# Gulpfile problems

Tags: npm, sass, gulp, gulpfile

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdtJs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGC1u.png)

I got some problems with my gulpfile. it does`t compile my sass files into css an i have an error (

```
`Error in plugin "gulp-sass"
Message:

gulp-sass 5 does not have a default Sass compiler; please set one yourself.
Both the `sass` and `node-sass` packages are permitted.
For example, in your gulpfile:

  var sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));

The following tasks did not complete: watch, style
Did you forget to signal async completion?`
```

) when i try to run it. Browser sync works well enough but i cant compile. I have all modules i need (

```
"devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.4",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^5.0.0"
```

).